# Static Text created in CS3 changes when saved to CC

Tags: flash, fonts, adobe, animate-cc

I have a Flash CS3 file that contains Static Texts.
When I open the CS3 file in Animate CC, text is still looks the same, until I Save As CC version.
After saving as CC version, I close the file, when I open it again, the text is different but with the same properties.

Is there a fix for this. I need to save to CC version.

Comment: Does the text stay same size also in both CS5 and CC output SWF files? I hope this isn't just a silly interface / zoom setting issue. Does a new CC textfield with same font settings also make _"way bigger"_ text if compared side by side with existing one from CS5?

Comment: Yes, they are same  in output SWF. I edited the question, I discovered that the file was originally cs3, Also, a new scenario how the problem occurs.